# Innerhtml keeps adding up instead of replacing it - javascript - html

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml, innertext

I've got a pretty complicated code to explain and I'm not a native Englisch speaker so I'm trying to explain my problem with an simple example.

I've got this function (let's call it function check). I added an eventlistener to a button (let's call this button1). When the button is clicked the function is executed.

```
Function check () {
   if (document.getElementById("id1").hasAttribute("clicked")) {
      document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = '<p>Hello World!</p>;
   } else {
      document.getElementById("id2").innerText = "Hello you";
   }
}

button1.addEventListener("click", check);
```

So here's the problem: When it doesn't have the attribute it does display "Hello you".  Which  is great. Click again and its still displayed only once, great again. But if than later it does have the attribute and the button is clicked again, thank it displays both "Hello you" as "Hello world!" which is not great.

What is worse, and this happens if "Hello you" is or isn't already displayed, when I click the button again it keeps adding the innerHTML so even if "Hello world" is already displayed, it just adds it underneath everytime I click the button.

Is there a way to replace the text or html code that's already there?

I've tried looking it up on the internet but I can't find a solution. I'm a beginner so I hope you can help me with a easy way to fix this

Comment: 1.) `Function` is invalid here; use `function` - you should see this error in your console. 2.) Incude your html so we have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This

```js
function check () {

   if (document.getElementById("id1").hasAttribute("clicked")) {
      document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = '<p>Hello World!</p>';
   } else {
      document.getElementById("id2").innerText = "Hello you";
   }
}


document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", check);
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", changeAttr);

function changeAttr(){
document.getElementById("id1").setAttribute('clicked',true)
}
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="button2">Add Attribute </button>
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I can't use this option in my actual code. In hindsight, it wasn't very convenient of me to use an example like this. It did give me another idea and unfortunately that didn't work either, but I don't understand why either.

On second thought, I will still create a question with my entire code and try to explain it. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much!